# What is the difference between d:Source and d:DesignSource?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10, design-time, windows-10-mobile

There are two design-time attributes - `d:Source` and `d:DesignSource`. It seems both could be used for design data specification for CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GrouppedCollection"
                      IsSourceGrouped="true"
                      Source="{Binding GroupedItems}"
                      d:Source="{Binding GroupedItems,
                                         Source={d:DesignInstance
                                                   Type=vm:MyViewModel,
                                                   IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}" />
```

**OR**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="GrouppedCollection"
                      IsSourceGrouped="true"
                      Source="{Binding GroupedItems}"
                      d:DesignSource="{Binding GroupedItems,
                                               Source={d:DesignInstance
                                                         Type=vm:MyViewModel,
                                                         IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}" />
```

Is there any difference between them or they are just two names for the same thing?

Comment: Well, they are both prefixed with `d:` which means they will be ignored at run time. So there's that.

Comment: @MikeEason, well, true enough :). Although I'm more concerned about design time behavior.